# United Airlines travel documents needed for a permanent resident of Canada

Tags: usa, canada, united-airlines, montreal

Alright, the story is simple. I don't have a valid PR card with me, my new card will arrive by mail to my apartment in Montreal. A friend will mail it to me. Tomorrow I'm travelling

`MONTREAL -> NEW-YORK -> SAN-FRANCISCO`

So, will United demand to see my PR card (which I don't have), or will they let me leave? I don't know if this is important but I have a B1/B2 visa to travel to the USA.

I have read their site about document requirements, but the formulation is ambiguous. Any tips?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: They won't need to see your PR card to let you fly to the US, but they might want to know that you'll be able to return to Canada.  Normally they won't care about that until you arrive to board the return flight, but if your stay in the US is particularly short, they might care about it when you leave Canada.

Comment: I will be staying 3 weeks with my dad. What is your experience with US borders? What should I say? Or most importantly, what should I not say. I don't want to sound stupid @phoog

Comment: Your problem will not be with the US border authorities.  If there is any problem it will be with the airline.  I don't think there is much likelihood of a problem.  In any event, my experience won't be of much use as a guide in your case because I have never traveled with anyone in a situation similar to yours.

Comment: There are no exit formalities or immigration controls in the US. Your only hassle is to obtain a boarding pass from the airline. As long as you have your valid passport, which shows your B1/B2 and your Canadian status (not sure as a PR if you get a visa sticker or stamp in your passport), you can travel without issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the airlines are more concerned about your ability to enter the destination.  Since you have a B1/B2 for the United States, that aspect is covered.

Keep in mind, since you are traveling from Montreal, **99% you will clear US CPB before boarding your flight as Montreal (Trudeau) has a Preclearence facility**.  Meaning, you will have already crossed the biggest hurdle before even boarding the aircraft.  UA may do little more than glance at your travel docs, if even that.

If this is your first time entering the United States on that Visa, give you self some extra time as there are some formalities the Officers have to perform.  Just answer the questions truthfully.  **Lying or even appearing like you're lying is much worse than merely sounding stupid.**

Comment: thank you for the answer, I will be leaving for the airport in about 4 hours so I will comeback to update you guys! Thank you for the clear and concise answer!

Comment: 99.99%.  It is extremely, extremely rare not to pre-clear US CBP at Canadian airports that are so equipped.

Comment: @Johns-305 you were right! Thank you very much sir

Answer (score 0):

Johns-305 is correct in what he writes, but he does omit an important point. When you fly back to Canada the airline is going to want to see proof that you are allowed to enter Canada. That would normally be your PR card. Without that you may be denied boarding on your return. If you are allowed to enter Canada visa free because of your nationality anyway you may be OK, but otherwise this is a problem.

Comment: Like I said in my question, I'm expecting to get it while in San-Francisco. I was just worried for leaving the country

Comment: Missed that. I'll delete when able.